# How do I rotate the desktop on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, display, rotate

My angel pressed some thing and after that the Windows screen has rotated. It has become vertical. I have restarted, but it still shows the same.

How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: You own an angel?? :)

Comment: Just to be sure (as I've never seen rotating the display having this effect on the Windows task bar): you are referring to the whole screen, not just the task bar, right?

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy  +  1 - Do you have child ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function of your video card drivers.  Typically, the way to fix this is to go into the video card control center.  For AMD (ATI) cards, this is typically the Catalyst Control Center, for NVidia, it's the NVIDIA Control Panel.  I don't know what the name is for Intel.  In any case, you're looking for an option like "Rotate Desktop" or "Rotate Display".  Set it back to 0 degrees or landscape mode, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

#### Windows Screen Rotation

On rare occasions the Windows screen has accidentally rotated by pressing a certain specific key combination on an attached USB keyboard.

To set the rotation:

- Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> buttons
- Press up, down, left or right arrows

Comment: This is specific to those who have Intel IGPs.

Comment: @Sathya is correct, this only works with Intel....

Comment: True that this is specific to a particular graphics card, but it's the thing that always bites me when I sit down at someone else's PC.  It's helpful to know that ctrl-alt-arrows can quickly get you back.